# How to add yotpo review to custom page: magento2

Tags: magento2, custom, review

At website front side in custom page, i'm showing category list with name and image.
How can i show yotpo reviews with categories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one and for information please visit the below blog :

### https://support.yotpo.com/en/article/display-empty-stars-on-category-pages#adobe-commerce-formerly-magento-2

```
<!-- Yotpo's Star Rating with no Reviews Widget START -->
<?php 
    $rs_helper = $this->helper('Yotpo\Yotpo\Helper\RichSnippets');
    $array = $rs_helper->getRichSnippet($this); 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productYotpo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
?>
<?php if (isset($array["reviews_count"]) && $array["reviews_count"] != 0 ): ?>
    <div class="yotpo bottomLine bottomline-position"
        data-product-id="<?php echo $productYotpo->getId(); ?>"
        data-url="<?php echo $productYotpo->getProductUrl(); ?>">
    </div>    
<?php else: ?>
<div class="yotpo bottomline">
<div class="yotpo-bottomline pull-left star-clickable">  
    <span class="yotpo-stars"> 
     <span class="yotpo-icon yotpo-icon-empty-star pull-left"></span>
     <span class="yotpo-icon yotpo-icon-empty-star pull-left"></span>
     <span class="yotpo-icon yotpo-icon-empty-star pull-left"></span>
     <span class="yotpo-icon yotpo-icon-empty-star pull-left"></span>
     <span class="yotpo-icon yotpo-icon-empty-star pull-left"></span> </span>      
 <div class="yotpo-clr"></div> </div></div><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Yotpo's Star Rating with no Reviews Widget END -->
```

**For the star please try this code :**

> **if the review is empty then the star will not show.so there is must be one review for the product**

data-product-id : Here we can use product sku or product id to show review.

```
<div class="yotpo bottomLine"
data-appkey="[Paste App Key]"
data-domain="[Paste Domain url]" data-product-id="[Make it dynamic]" >
</div>
```